# Determine the best approximation of $|f^{(4)}(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

The first task was to show the inequality \begin{equation} \left|\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}\right| \leq \frac{e^{p^2}}{p^4}, \quad p > 0 \end{equation} when given the fact that $|f(z)| \leq e^{|z|^2} $. I did that by using the Cauchy inequality theorem.

Next task:

Determine the best approximation of $|f^{(4)}(0)|$ if $f$ is analytical in the whole plane and \begin{equation}\left|\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}\right| \leq \frac{e^{p^2}}{p^4}, \quad p > 0 \end{equation}

The solution is: $|f^{(4)}(0)| \leq 6e^2$. This implies that $p=\sqrt{2}$.

In my own solution I only get this far: $|f^{(4)}(0)| \leq 4! \cdot \frac{e^{p^2}}{p^4}$

and then I get stuck. Why should we use $p=\sqrt{2}$ for the best approximation?

Comment: Try to find the smallest value of $e^{p^2}/p^4$. To do this, define the function $g(x)=e^{x^2}/x^{4}$, find its minimum.

Comment: @ThibautDumont That's a good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let $\phi(p)=\dfrac{e^{p^{2}}}{p^{4}}$ for $p>0$, when doing the elementary calculus one shows that $\phi'(\sqrt{2})=0$, try to argue that the point makes $\phi$ minimum.

Actually $\phi'(p)=\dfrac{2e^{p^{2}}(p+\sqrt{2})(p-\sqrt{2})}{p^{5}}$, so on the interval $(0,\sqrt{2})$, $\phi$ is decreasing, and on the interval $(\sqrt{2},\infty)$, $\phi$ is increasing, so the minimum attains at $p=\sqrt{2}$.